# When to use np.quantile and np.percentile?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to distinguish the scenario in which `np.quantile()` or `np.percentile()` should be used.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[10, 7, 4], [3, 2, 1]])
>>> np.quantile(a, 0.5)
3.5
>>> np.percentile(a, 50)
3.5
```

Both of them give the same result and call `_quantile_unchecked()` in their implementation.

What are the best use cases?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156778/percentile-vs-quantile-vs-quartile

Answer (score 28):

They are equivalent. If you'd rather specify q from [0, 1], use np.quantile. For [0, 100], use np.percentile.

Docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html